# Recommendations of bypassing show/hide javascript with anchors

Tags: html, anchor, show-hide

I am trying to bypass a show/hide javascript action by using anchors. The reason why I want to use anchors is because I want to give someone a direct link (ex:page.html#content) to a specific div that would show the content within that div.

For our website, we've used javascript to show content and hide content since we had many different divs to expose. Now, I've tried adding in a simple anchor and typing in the link on a browser, but did not work since the javascript had to run to run and hide the content.

I understand that the show/hide javascript action actually shows and hide the content so this might not work. Is there any way to go around this and what would you recommend to go from here? I appreciate any recommendations.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What I've done in the past is to use anchors to trigger the javascript that shows/hides data.

So every action that can happen is triggered by an anchor tag with the href as `"#<whatever>"`.  Whenever an anchor (hyperlink) is clicked, it updates the url with the proper anchor and triggers the hashchange event in window.

Whenever that event fires I just have a switch statement that analyzes the hashtag and figures out what dynamic content needs to be changed.

The last part of this is to call the function with the switch statement at the dom ready event so that if somebody bookmarked the page with an anchor, it will know to load whatever dynamic content that specific hash triggers.